# How to push data to an array who is a key of a object in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have a Object like this:

```
 let myObject = {key:[]};
```

---

And I try to push some data to the key in the myObject:

```
myObject.key.push({name:'Mostafa',family:'Saadatnia'});
```

What is the typescripts error tells me is:

> Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)

How can I fix that? I don't want to fill data on definition-time. All of I need is fill that in the runtime

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All of you need is add a kind of data type to your object **`myObject`** for example **`any`**:

```
let myObject:any = {key:[]};
myObject.key.push({name:'Mostafa',family:'Saadatnia'});
```

---

**Your codes works as well.**

Answer (score 0):

So, when you assign something as `[]`, TS assumes that its type is `[]`, ie, an array of length 0. To avoid this, you can obviously go the `any` route, but then you don't get type-checking. The proper way to do this is to give the key property a type:

```js
type Obj = {
   name : string;
   family: string;
}
let myObject:{key: Obj[]} = {key:[]};
myObject.key.push({name:'Mostafa',family:'Saadatnia'});
```